# Every for loop prints on a new line, even though it shouldn't

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a 3-letter name generator for Minecraft, and I was planning on sharing this with my non-existent friends.

```java
package bored;
import java.util.Random;
public class Yay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr={"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_"};
        int i;
        int f;
        for (f=0; f<10; f++) {
            for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
                Random r=new Random();
                int randomNumber=r.nextInt(arr.length);
                System.out.print(arr[randomNumber]);
            System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should print something like "3ab" "9dl"
but instead it prints

3

a

b

9

d

l

Comment: you want to move the call to `System.out.println("");` outside the inner for-loop.

Comment: unfortunately i already tried that and it didn't work

Comment: I posted an answer which seems to work when I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're calling `System.out.println("")`, inside the innermost for loop. Based on your expected output and indentation, I suspect you meant to write:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Yay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr={"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_"};

        for (int f=0; f<10; f++) {
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                Random r=new Random();
                int randomNumber=r.nextInt(arr.length);
                System.out.print(arr[randomNumber]);
            }
            System.out.println(); // Outside of the for loop
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently calling the newline print statement inside the inner for loop. You can change the code from this

```
for (f=0; f<10; f++) {
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        Random r=new Random();
        int randomNumber=r.nextInt(arr.length);
        System.out.print(arr[randomNumber]);
    System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

to this

```
for (f=0; f<10; f++) {
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        Random r=new Random();
        int randomNumber=r.nextInt(arr.length);
        System.out.print(arr[randomNumber]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `System.out.println("");` outside of the inner `for-loop`.

Also I would not init the `f` and `i` variables outside your for-loop because you only need them inside:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr={"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_"};

    for (int f=0; f<10; f++) {
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            Random r=new Random();
            int randomNumber=r.nextInt(arr.length);
            System.out.print(arr[randomNumber]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must move `System.out.println(""); outside the inner for loop.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr={"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_"};
        int i;
        int f;
        for (f=0; f<10; f++) {
            for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
                Random r=new Random();
                int randomNumber=r.nextInt(arr.length);
                System.out.print(arr[randomNumber]);

            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```